# How to create a calendar like iCal/Google Calendar using Javascript/jQuery/D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, calendar

Would like to create a calendar similar to iCal or Google Calendar using Java script..for browser..Couldn't find a lot of info when I googled..thought I'd ask here..

could you please point me to any resources?

Answer (score 0):

Consider FullCalendar, a jquery calendar library: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/